# Is Spring MVC using setter methods to set the properties of ModelAttribute objects?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Is Spring MVC using getters and setters to set the values of ModelAttribute objects? Can you please cite me sources that says so. And if not, how could we force Spring MVC to use setters to set the properties of the model object?

Thanks.

Comment: Your question as asked doesn't make sense.  ModelAttribute is an annotation so there should be no 'getting' or 'setting' of instances of @ModelAttribute at runtime.  Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if this really answers the question, but I found this quote in the documentation:

> Command or form objects **to bind request parameters to bean properties (via setters)** or directly to fields, with customizable type conversion, depending on @InitBinder methods and/or the HandlerAdapter configuration. ...  The ModelAttribute annotation can be used on a method argument to customize the model attribute name used.

This seems to imply that setters will be used if available, with direct update of the fields as a fallback.

But if you want a definitive answer, look at the source code.

Comment: You're right Spring MVC is really using the setters but not at all times. Say if I have <input name="myList[0].p1"> and getMyList() is a method returns a new instance of list containing all items from a set property. Everything fails because Spring is using the getters to populate the items on my list.  I was expecting spring not to use the getters to put items on my list but initialize its own list instead and use the setters to set it back on my form. It's like I'm giving Spring a new list of items from a set, and spring puts something in that list but it doesn't set it back. What a pitfall.

Comment: @supertonsky - You are not entirely making sense.  How do use a "getter" to populate something?

Comment: no, it's the Spring that's using the getter to get the list to insert items in it. I mentioned it so you could get the idea why it is failing it's because it doesn't return the actual property but simply returns a new list containing items from a Set property.

Comment: It's like this getMyList(){ return new ArrayList(this.mySet) }; setMyList( List list ){ this.mySet.addAll( list ); }

Comment: given that, if Spring uses my getMyList() to populate the items then it becomes pointless because that list is a new instance. Spring must set it back or it will be pointless, nothing is referencing that new list. I don't want to create a temporary list instance variable on my POJO just to make this work.

Comment: @supertonsky - I cannot figure out what your comments are saying and I'm too tired to try.  Please take the time to rewrite your Question to be more clear.  And please try to avoid writing things that do not make literal sense.  For instance you wrote (at least 2 times) that Spring is using getters to set something.  This is literally nonsensical.

Comment: That isn't what I said, I said Spring is using getters to get the List to insert items in it. I didn't say Spring is using getters to set something.

Comment: @supertonsky - Actually, it **>>IS<<** what you said.  Reread what you wrote.

Comment: Forgive me for my first comment but I clarified it in my second comment I wrote QUOTE it's the Spring that's _using the getter to get the list_ **to insert** items in it. UNQUOTE

Answer (score 0):

I also encounter this problem, the situation is below:

the code snippet:

Product.java

```
public class Product {

    private String name;
    private String imageStr;
    private List<ProdutImage> productImageList;

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<ProductImage> getProductImageList() {
        return this.productImageList;
    }

    public void setProductImageList(List<ProductImage> productImageList) {
        this.productImageList = productImageList;
        if (productImageList != null) {
            this.imageStr = [...]// convert list to json string
        }
    }

}
```

it didn't set the "imageStr" directly, but base on the image list field, the jsp page likes:

```
 <form>
      <input type="text" name="product.name"/>
      <input type="text" name="product.productImageList[0]"/>
      <input type="text" name="product.productImageList[1]"/>
      <input type="text" name="product.productImageList[2]"/>
   </form>
```

when submit the form, the "name" and "productImageList" all can be populated successfully, one thing is different, I put breakpoint both in "setName" and "setProductImageList", we can find that the "setName" is be called, but not the "setProductImageList", because this, the "imageStr" is null.